# Scons: Deal with backslashes in classpath

Tags: filepath, scons

Somewhere deep in an Scons build tree that I don't know the details of, a path is being added to the CLASSPATH argument passed to javac.

During the build, I get an error message like:

`warning: [path] bad path element "C:Userraedengitrojecesource.jar"`

The path that is actually supposed to be passed to javac is "C:\Users\Braeden\git\project\resource.jar".

I'm assuming that what's going on here is that Scons is generating a Windows-styled path somewhere along the way and Python is interpreting the backslashes as escape characters.

This path (nor a relative version of it) is not hard-coded into any build files. Is a catch-all solution available to this problem, or am I going to have to scour the project for the place where this path is generated and correct it?

Comment: Where is the path coming from? Is it an input to the Scons script? Is it an environment variable, like CLASSPATH?

Comment: @ChristianHujer Actually, I got it fixed. Turns out the actual path I was running it on had a space in it, and removing it fixed the issue.